# Double index Pandas shifting along one of the two index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, shift

I have a dataframe like the following (double index dataframe):

```
index1      index2  close   
......
2020-05-01  AAAA    11      
2020-05-01  BBBB    21      
2020-05-02  AAAA    12.5    
2020-05-02  BBBB    22.5    
2020-05-02  CCCC    32.5    
2020-05-03  AAAA    13      
2020-05-03  BBBB    23      
2020-05-03  CCCC    33
```

I need to create a new column with the value of the close column shifted. But just shifting one of the two indexes (index1). Like the following:

```
index1      index2  close   close_shifted
......
2020-05-01  AAAA    11      12.5
2020-05-01  BBBB    21      22.5
2020-05-01  CCCC            32.5
2020-05-02  AAAA    12.5    13
2020-05-02  BBBB    22.5    23
2020-05-02  CCCC    32.5    33
2020-05-03  AAAA    13      
2020-05-03  BBBB    23      
2020-05-03  CCCC    33
```

Is that possible?

df['close'].shift(-3) is not the solution I need

Comment: What's wrong with `df['close'].shift(-n)`?

Comment: n is not always the same number for the different index1s. Like the example (n==2 at 2020-05-01 but n==3 at the other dates)

Comment: in the sample, `2020-05-01` doesn't have 'CCCC`. why does the desired output have it?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index1':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],'index2':['A','B','A','B','C','A','B','C'],
                   'close':[11,21,12.5,22.5,32.5,13,23,33]})
df.set_index(['index1','index2'], inplace=True)

df['shifted'] = df.groupby(level=1).shift(-1)
df
```

[image]

in your desired output I think CCCC at 2020-05-01 is a mistake (we don't have it in the original input df)